# How to read cell values from existing excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I want to read the each cell value in excel file, But i am not able to get the cell values even after trying different examples in NET. I am not getting result with the following code, can any one get back on this. I am using .net framework 2.0

```
string filePath = "F:/BulkTest.xlsx";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
ExcelApp.Visible = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath, Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,Missing.Value);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sh = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets["Sheet1"];
Range excelRange = sh.UsedRange;

for (int i=2; i<= excelRange.Count + 1 ; i++)
{
    string values = sh.Cells[i,2].ToString();
}
```

Comment: `wb.Sheets["Sheet1"].ToString();`? Where are you reading the cell? To read say Cell A1, you have to use `sh.Cells[1, 1]`

Comment: Do not iterate over each separate cell. That is to slow.
If you do something maintanable use a excel-reader library like EPPLus

Comment: No... I gave you an example on how to use the `.Cells[]` property :) What you are doing is reading the value of cell B2 in every loop. Instead of looping, why not store the values in an Array?

Comment: Ok back to basic question. Why are you looping through every cell to get it's value? What is you main objective?

Comment: i need to get all values in column and i have to pass those values to stored procedure...

Comment: Then why are you using `UsedRange`. Set the range to the relevant column and then read it into an array.

Comment: Till now i am trying to take cell values directly to variables, now i will try to take cell values to an array using Range. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Till now i am trying to take cell values directly to variables, now i will try to take cell values to an array using Range. Thanks!!!! – Teja Varma 13 mins ago

No. I didn't even mean that :) As I mentioned in the comment that you can store the entire range in an array. That doesn't mean that you need to loop though each cell to store it in an array. You can directly assign the values of the range to the array. See this example.

```
xlRng = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A20");

Object arr = xlRng.Value;

foreach (object s in (Array)arr)
{
    MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
}
```

Comment: For some reason I get null on xlRng.Value.

Comment: @DoodleKana see if the excel file is being saved. May be the file is in edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would be to use:

```
Sheet.Cells[row,col].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: That's the common answer. It doesn't work. I tried it with interop 15, 14, and I get a CS1061 error

Answer (score 0):

C# code
Tested OK

```
string s = xlSheet.UsedRange.Cells[1,   7].Value.ToString();
//or
string d = xlSheet.UsedRange.Cells[1, "G"].Value.ToString();
```

Full Code

```
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlSheet;

        string Path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

        xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path + "\\myfile.xlsx");
        xlApp.Visible = true;
        xlSheet = xlBook.ActiveSheet;

        string s = xlSheet.UsedRange.Cells[1, 7].Value.ToString();
        string d = xlSheet.UsedRange.Cells[1, "G"].Value.ToString();

        xlBook.Close();
        xlApp.Quit();

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheet);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlBook);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```