# how to assign value(from excel) in Wintable row through coded UI

Tags: c#, excel, coded-ui-tests

`Enter code here` .. I am trying to automate application through coded UI. I am stuck at this point:

Application has Table(ControlType : WinTable) and it is divided into 7 rows(ControlType : Row) like this:

FilePath   :  C:\test.txt
Printer Name  : xyz
..
..

According to requirement, value of "FilePath" will take from excel sheet and same for "Printer name".

Here is the code:

```
WinWindow winP = new WinWindow();
winP.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name, "Create     Print Job", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));

     WinTable tbP = new WinTable(winP);
     tbP.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(WinTable.PropertyNames.Name,     "Properties Window", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));

      Excel.Workbook MyBook = null;
      Excel.Application MyApp = null;
      Excel.Worksheet MySheet = null;

      MyApp = new Excel.Application();
      MyApp.Visible = false;

       MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\DEPCON\\DataInput.xlsx");
       MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1]; 
        Excel.Range range = MySheet.UsedRange;
        for (int rCnt = 2; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
        {
           for (int cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
           {
              WinRow row = tbP.GetRow(0);
             row.Value= (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2; //  row.Value is showing read only.  
                        }
        }
```

I also tried string[] values = tbP.GetContent();. Can anyone tell me how to assign a value on Row from excel sheet, one-by-one? I also checked WinTable function. All functions are related to get a value. I do not know how to set(assign) a value.

Comment: You know that Excel does not really support an automated mode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213255/how-to-read-cell-values-from-existing-excel-file

Comment: Hi Bayeni, I am facing issue to assign a value in WinTable Row(in my example “Filepath” will read from excel  sheet. Here, I am not able to access Wintable Row). In this link(stackoverflow.com/questions/16213255/), he was showing how to read data from excel sheet. I have to read data from excel sheet and assign to Wintable Row one by one. Any Idea ??