# Using assertions to compare two excel files

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, assertions

Im using Visual Studio to create an automated test that creates two excel sheets. As a final check, I need to compare the content of these two excel sheets and ensure that they are equal. Is there any way to do this with assertions?

Something like `Assert.AreEqual(file1, file2);`?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to use Office Interop to open both spreadsheets, and do a loop through the rows and columns comparing each cells value. You can read up more on Office Interop here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213255/how-to-read-cell-values-from-existing-excel-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [Mangist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1480165/mangist) for guidance on this. Ive written the following to compare two excel files:

```
public bool compareFiles(string filePath1, string filePath2)
    {
        bool result = false;
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();

        //Open files to compare
        Excel.Workbook workbook1 = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath1);
        Excel.Workbook workbook2 = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath2);

        //Open sheets to grab values from
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook1.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook2.Sheets[1];

        //Get the used range of cells
        Excel.Range range = worksheet2.UsedRange;
        int maxColumns = range.Columns.Count;
        int maxRows = range.Rows.Count;

        //Check that each cell matches
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxColumns; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= maxRows; j++)
            {
                if (worksheet1.Cells[j, i].Value == worksheet2.Cells[j, i].Value)
                {
                    result = true;
                }
                else
                    result = false;
            }
        }


        //Close the workbooks
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet1);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet2);
        workbook1.Close();
        workbook2.Close();
        excel.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);

        //Tell us if it is true or false
        return result;
    }
```

And using an assertion to check result:

```
Assert.IsTrue(compareFiles(testFile, compareFile), "Output files do not match.");
```

Comment: Other than last cell, if any cells value differs in both workbooks it will pass the testcase.

Answer (score 2):

Can you convert the expected/actual Excel sheets to a text format, such as CSV?

If so, you could use [Approval Tests](http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/) instead. This allows you to have a text file as your "expected" test result. When tests fail it can show you the actual result of the test, diff'd against the expected result.

[image: Diff view]

Screenshot taken from [this review](http://beletsky.net/2011/12/approval-tests-alternative-view-on-test.html) of Approval Tests.

Answer (score 0):

One Option will be using Open source library called as `EPPlus`. You can download and refer it in you automated test application. EPPlus gives you multiple ways to read an excel file and compare. One such option is C# Datatable. Here is a sample code..

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableFromExcel(string path, bool hasHeader = true)
{ 
using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        pck.Load(stream);
    }
    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();  
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
    {
        tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
    }
    var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
    for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
    {
        var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
        DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();
        foreach (var cell in wsRow)
        {
            row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
        }
    }
    return tbl;
}
}
```

For both the Excel files , same process can be adopted, and it will give you the desired results.